# Why coroutine's await function doesn't finish?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying coroutines to make network request using Retrofit on background thread. First of all, I changed Retrofit's `Call` to `Deferred`. Here's how it looks like:

```
 @GET("some_endpoint")
 fun getData(@Query("id") id: Int): Deferred<JsonObject>
```

So, in order to use above function, I created `suspend` function and used `await`. Here's how it looks:

```
 suspend fun getNetworkData(id: Int): Resource<JsonObject> {
    try {
        val data = api.getData(id).await()

        return Resource.success(data)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return Resource.error()
    }

}
```

But, when I debug my app, `await` never finishes. Break point never comes to return statement. So, I decided to replace `Deferred` to Retrofit's `Call` again. And, instead of await, I decided to use Retrofit's `execute`. Of course, I removed suspend keyword.
Here's how it looks now:

```
 @GET("some_endpoint")
 fun getData(@Query("id") id: Int): Call<JsonObject>


 fun getNetworkData(id: Int): Resource<JsonObject> {
    try {
        val data = api.getData(id).execute()

        return Resource.success(data.body())

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return Resource.error()
    }

}
```

Then, it worked like a charm. I successfully got my data. But, I want to understand why this happened. In others words, why coroutine `await` call didn't finish or even didn't run `catch` block, when `Retrofit`'s `Call` and `execute` finished task successfully?

If it is needed, I provide how I call above `getNetworkData` function:

```
launch {
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repo.getNetworkData(id) }
  //do something

    }
```

Comment: Did you add `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory` when initializing Retrofit? https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Hey @neo did you get the answer why this is happening?. I'm also facing same issue await stuck and never finishes

Comment: @SolankiZeel Hey. I don't remember how I solved it. It was a lot of years ago :(